# Filtering Using MapReduce in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, filtering

I want to filter records from given file based on some criteria,i want my criteria to be if value of third field is equal to some value then retrive that record and save it in output file .i am taking CSV file as input.Can anyone suggest something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need scalability you can use hadoop in the following way: 
Install Hadoop, install hive, put your csv files into HDFS. 

 define the CSV file as external table (http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/language_manual/data-manipulation-statements.html) and then you can write SQLs against the CSV file. Results of SQL can be then exported back to CSV.

Comment: if i want to do it using mapredcue only is there any way? i dont want to use hive

Comment: You can use hadoop streaming in this case. In a natshell - hadoop will feed your script with input data, and collect outputs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i have never used hadoop streaming but i will try

Comment: it has inferior performance then regular MR, but it is simplest to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would probably be to use [pig](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/)
something like

```
orig = load 'filename.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (first,second,third:chararray,...);

filtered_orig= FILTER orig by third=="somevalue"; 

store filtered_orig into 'newfilename' using PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: hmmm i would like to do it using mapreduce onlt is there any way?

Comment: pig generates map-reduce - you can write the same logic yourself in Java